# Create a username using Python

Tags: python, sys

I'm just learning Python and have to create a program that has a function that takes as arguments a first and last name and creates a username. The username will be the first letter of the first name in lowercase, the last 7 of the last name in lowercase, and the total number of characters in the first and last names.  For example, Jackie Robinson would be jobinson14. I have to use sys.argv.

This is my code:

```
import sys

def full_name(first, last):
    first = input(first)
    last = input(last)
    username = lower((first[0] + last[:7])) + len(first+last)
    return username
first = sys.argv[1]
last = sys.argv[2]
username = full_name(first, last)    
print ("Your username is",username)
```

When entering Darth Vader

```
Expected output:
Your username is dvader10

Actual output:
Darth
```

Please help!

Comment: Why do you use sys.argv then overwrite it with input()?

Comment: Make up your mind. Are you passing parameters through function call or requesting them through terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actual output:
> Darth

Not exactly. You are using `input(first)`, which is waiting for you to type something...

Using `sys.argv` means you need to provide the arguments when running the code

```
python app.py Darth Vader
```

And if you remove the `input()` lines, this would return *without* prompting for input, and not show `Darth`

---

As shown, you are trying to read from arguments **and** prompt for input.

If you did want to prompt, then you need to remove the import

```
def full_name(first, last):
    return (first[0] + last[-7:] + str(len(first+last))).lower()

first = input('First Name: ')
last = input('Last Name: ')
username = full_name(first, last)    
print("Your username is",username)
```

And just run the script directly. But you say you have to use `sys.argv`, so the solution you're looking for is to not use `input()` at all.

Comment: I am required to use sys.argv. Where would that fit in this code?

Comment: Read the first half of the post.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `input()` function and assign it to `first`, like this:

```
    first = input(first)
```

what you're doing is printing `first` (so `"Darth"`), waiting for the user to enter something, and then assigning *that* to `first`.  That's why your script prints `Darth` -- it's waiting for you to tell it what `first` is.

But since you already passed the first and last name via the command line, you don't want to do that -- so just remove those two `input` lines.  Make sure to convert the `len` to a `str` before you add it to the other strings!

```
def full_name(first, last):
    return (first[0] + last[:7] + str(len(first+last))).lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You ask to input names even if they are in `sys.argv`.
2. `Input("Enter name: ")` accepts string that help to understand what you should input.
3. As OneCricketeer commented, you trying to get first 7 letters instead of last.

Here is an example that accepts names from command line otherwise prompt to input.

```py
import sys


def full_name(_first, _last):
    return f"{(_first[0] + _last[-7:])}{len(_first + _last)}"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    first = last = ""

    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1]:
            first = sys.argv[1].lower()
        if sys.argv[2]:
            last = sys.argv[2].lower()

    if not first:
        first = input("Input first name: ").lower()
    if not last:
        last = input("Input last name: ").lower()

    username = full_name(first, last)
    print("Your username is", username)
```